# Problem with removing post tags programmatically

Tags: custom-taxonomy, tags

I use the following function in order to retrieve tags of a post, remove an element from the array and then set the result to the post:

```
$post_tags = wp_get_post_terms( $post_id );
foreach ( $post_tags as $key => $tag) {
    $tag_string = http_build_query( $tag );
    if( 0 != strpos( $tag_string , 'tag-to-be-deleted' ) ) {
            unset( $post_tags[$key] );
    }
}
wp_set_post_terms ($post_id, $post_tags, 'post_tag');
```

Then I get a bug inside the wp_set_post_terms function, that says the $post_tags parameter should be a string and not an array...what am I doing wrong here?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code looks little clunky, `http_build_query()` is definitely not meant for such. Also what you are fetching is not simple array, but array of tag objects.

My take:

```
$post_tags = wp_get_post_terms( $post_id, 'post_tag', array( 'fields'=>'names' ) );
$pos = array_search( 'tag-to-be-deleted', $post_tags );

if( false !== $pos ) {

    unset( $post_tags[$pos] );
    wp_set_post_terms ($post_id, $post_tags, 'post_tag');
}
```

Comment: You should use this one instead of mine, as wp_get_post_terms here returns only the field you want, and it's a array :)

Answer (score 1):

[wp_get_post_terms()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_post_terms) seems to return a object, and you need to pass a array to `wp_set_post_terms`:

```
$post_tags = wp_get_post_terms( $post_id );
$new_tags = array();
foreach ( $post_tags as $tag) {
    $tag_string = http_build_query( $tag );
    if( strpos( $tag_string , 'tag-to-be-deleted' ) === false ) {
            $new_tags[] = $tag->name;
    }
}
wp_set_post_terms ($post_id, $new_tags, 'post_tag');
```